# Corrupted PDF file after requests.get() with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, python-requests

I am trying to download a PDF file using requests.get(). It works for most test PDF files I found but for this case it does not and the file is corrupted. If I open the URL with a browser and save the file it is working just fine. I have tried to download it in chunks using 'Stream' but with the same result. Could you please explain to me what am I missing?

```
import requests

file_url = 'http://medianet.edmond-de-rothschild.fr/edram/pdf/kiid_fr0010172767_en_20200120_20200128_1954.pdf'


headers = {'Content-type': 'application/pdf'}
r = requests.get(file_url, headers=headers)

with open("python.pdf", "wb") as pdf:
    pdf.write(r.content)
    pdf.close()
```

Comment: You are likely missing that you are not downloading the PDF *at all*. Check what you downloaded -- it is HTML.

Comment: Do you know why it returns HTML despite the url ending in PDF explicitly? How should I get the pdf part of it in the easiest way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixing the **header** information makes it work.

```py
import requests

file_url = "http://medianet.edmond-de-rothschild.fr/edram/pdf/kiid_fr0010172767_en_20200120_20200128_1954.pdf"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.20.1",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Postman-Token": "8eb5df70-4da6-4ba1-a9dd-e68880316cd9,30ac79fa-969b-4a24-8035-26ad1a2650e1",
    "Host": "medianet.edmond-de-rothschild.fr",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
}

r = requests.get(file_url, file_url, headers=headers)

with open("python.pdf", "wb") as pdf:
    pdf.write(r.content)
```

Comment: Thank you. It does work but I am not sure what data from the header made it work and why. If you know please share so I can debug similar cases on my own in the future.

Comment: I used [postman](https://www.postman.com/) to send the get request first. Postman does some **http** magic underneath to produce the appropriate header. I just picked up that information. :D

Comment: @RedowanDelowar I am curious to know exactly how you did this. any additional details you can add?

Comment: @NicThibodeaux Most likely the user agent and accept header is doing the trick. Try removing all other headers and see if it’s working. If so, it means the server only allows downloading a pdf when the agent is of a certain type.